# Adding a summary header for columns and rows

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I would like to add a single header for a group of columns and rows.

I've tried using `ColumnGroupHeaderLayer` but the text is in the centre of the column. Instead I would like it to always have the text drawn in the centre of the visible cell and always remain in the same position as I scroll.

I've looked through a lot of documentation but I'm struggling to find anything on how I could do this.

**Example**

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this with NatTable?

Answer (score 1):

I answered the question in the forum where you posted at the same time
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1099224/